# Share Dialog code not working in IE correctly

Tags: facebook, share

This code from FB is working great on Chrome, FF, Safari, but on IE it redirects the page to FB instead of opening the new window. Does anyone know why this might be?

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bow-Wow-Barrier/183857675040526" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
    <img border="0"; img src="http://www.bowwowbarrier.com/images/sharebutton.gif">
</a>
```

Comment: Is your FB account already login in IE ?

Comment: I see that it worked for you maybe it is in my cache I will empty it and see

Comment: mark answer as accepted answer please by clicking the "Tick" sign on left side of my answer under votes count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mistake in Code. You must be login in browser to use this otherwise it should show fb login page.

here's the screenshot of working example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must be login to use this. Otherwise, you won't get sharing box window rather it will show fb login box.

Comment: I cleared the caching in IE and then logged in on facebook this still does not work at all for me. :-(